# Append to JSON file from form entry

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a **.json** file stored on my server in **www/ajax/data.json** with the following contents:

**data.json**

```
{
  "Endorsements": [{
    "Name": "Bob",
    "Date": "01/02/2017",
    "Message": "How's it going?"
  }, {
    "Name": "Sally",
    "Date": "01/01/2017",
    "Message": "Konichiwa"
  }, {
    "Name": "Sue",
    "Date": "01/10/2017",
    "Message": "Peace be unto you"
  }, {
    "Name": "Roger",
    "Date": "02/12/2017",
    "Message": "Namaste"
  }, {
    "Name": "Zed",
    "Date": "09/12/2017",
    "Message": "sup"
  }, {
    "Name": "Quail",
    "Date": "10/12/2017",
    "Message": "Chirp"
  }]
}
```

The **data.json** contents are successfully displayed and refreshed every 5 seconds on my **messages.php** page through an ajax function in **messages.js**.

On **messages.php** I have a `<form>` where users can leave a new message. The typed entries in the **Name**, **Date**, and **Message** fields are stored in localStorage through functions in **messages.js**.

How can I retrieve the localStorage data and use it to append a new message entry onto my **data.json** file?

Comment: readen this ?https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I already know how to store and output data to/from localStorage on html/php pages. Getting the data onto a .json file is a different beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code can help you, its just a function used to add an object to an existing json variable.

```js
var json = JSON.stringify({
  "Endorsements": [{
    "Name": "Bob",
    "Date": "01/02/2017",
    "Message": "How's it going?"
  }, {
    "Name": "Sally",
    "Date": "01/01/2017",
    "Message": "Konichiwa"
  }, {
    "Name": "Sue",
    "Date": "01/10/2017",
    "Message": "Peace be unto you"
  }, {
    "Name": "Roger",
    "Date": "02/12/2017",
    "Message": "Namaste"
  }, {
    "Name": "Zed",
    "Date": "09/12/2017",
    "Message": "sup"
  }, {
    "Name": "Quail",
    "Date": "10/12/2017",
    "Message": "Chirp"
  }]
});

localStorage.setItem("newObject", JSON.stringify({
 "Name": "test",
  "Date": "01/02/2017",
  "Message": "This is a test"
}));

function addToJsonFile(){
 if(localStorage.getItem("newObject") !== undefined && localStorage.getItem("newObject") !== ""){
   var jsonObjects = JSON.parse(json);
    jsonObjects.Endorsements[jsonObjects.Endorsements.length] = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("newObject"));
    json = JSON.stringify(jsonObjects)
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Still had to go through some weird loopholes, but wouldn't have been able to do it without this starting point.